# What does 'make it into' mean?

Tags: meaning, usage

I looked the expression up in a number of dictionary to no avail. What does 'it' refer to?

> Any game that involves more than one person involves socializing,
>   whether it’s cooperating during a scavenger hunt or competing to see
>   who can get the most balls in a basket. Playing games with kids
>   teaches team work, the consequences of cheating, and how to be good
>   sports whether they win or lose. It’s not hard to see how those skills
>   **make it into** the daily lives of kids in the classroom, on play dates, and later in life in the workplace. But like all things we hope
>   to teach our children, learning to cooperate or to compete without
>   being a jerk takes practice. Humans aren’t naturally good at losing,
>   so there will be tears, yelling, and cheating, and maybe somebody will
>   even knock over the board, scattering pieces under the couch when she
>   loses a game, but that’s okay. The point is, playing games with kids
>   allows them a safe place to practice getting along, following rules,
>   and learning how to be graceful in defeat. So when your kids deserve a
>   technical foul for the fits they’re pitching over a game, call it
>   quits for then, but definitely come back to more games later. If you
>   do that enough you’ll start to see more mature players coming to the
>   table.

https://heatherswainbooks.com/play-these-games-introduction/

Comment: A similar use: "The song **made it into** the charts."

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence:

> It’s not hard to see how those skills **make it** into the daily lives of kids in the classroom, on play dates, and later in life in the workplace.

**"make it"** refer to the fact that those skills (team work, consequences of cheating, fair play etc..)  are directly used in the daily lives of the kids.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam Webster:

c : to gain a place on or in
make the team
the story made the papers [could also be said: made it into the papers]

This is similar: to gain a place in the lives of children.